# How to uninistall phpmyadmin

Tags: apt, dpkg, uninstall, phpmyadmin

I installed phpmyadmin using this method

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48552306/how-to-install-phpmyadmin-4-7-7-on-ubuntu/48559715

Now I see that new version is out, I would like to completely remove installed and install the new one. I tried several ways to uninstall but unsuccessful. Here what I got:

```
sudo apt-get purge phpmyadmin*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'phpmyadmin' for glob 'phpmyadmin*'
Package 'phpmyadmin' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 28 not upgraded.

sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
dpkg-query: package 'phpmyadmin' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: phpmyadmin is not installed
```

Question is, what is the right uninstallation way for my type of installation?

Thanks,
Val

Comment: For future reference, if you don't use `apt-get` or `dpkg` to install, you can't use them to uninstall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same issue on my system a while back. Post some research, I came across these commands. They are quite old, yet they worked for me. Try executing these commands in the given order:

- `sudo dpkg -P phpmyadmin`
- `sudo rm -f /etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf`
- `sudo service apache2 restart`
- To remove all the remaining files, execute `sudo apt-get autoremove phpmyadmin`

Comment: Thanks for answer, but didn`t helped.

sudo dpkg -P phpmyadmin
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove phpmyadmin which isn't installed

I still able to connect to phpmyadmin

Comment: no issues we can find some other solution. you are using v4.7.7 (the same version you installed from the link)only right?

Comment: yes, Version information: 4.7.7

Comment: Since you installed it from the Ubuntu repositories, try this command

`sudo apt-get purge phpmyadmin`

The "purge" instead of "remove" instructs it to remove its configuration files too, including the configuration it added to Apache's configuration directories.
P.S - You tried `sudo apt-get purge phpmyadmin*`. Now try it without putting "*".

Comment: it says that phpadmin is not installed

$ sudo apt-get purge phpmyadmin
[sudo] password for ***:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package 'phpmyadmin' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 28 not upgraded.

Comment: are you sure it still is installed on your system?. Every command that you try states "its not installed". 
As a last resort, try this: 
1) - Open your `/home` folder and press `Ctrl` + `h` together to showcase hidden files. 2) See if you can find any folder by the name `.phpmyadmin` 3) If yes, simply delete it and if there is no folder may be you have uninstalled it completely.

Comment: it was a folder in my home dir named phpmyadmin, it also `/var/www/html/phpmyadmin#` still in place, maybe I need delete this too?

Comment: you must bro. Any file or folder left unattended can enforce the issue you are encountering.  These commands worked for me, not able to understand what went wrong on your end.